# Ruby On Rails 4 - Issue with Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to RoR and have been working on setting up my environment for the last few days (running Mountain Lion). I've finally gotten to the point where I can develop and decided to start a Trial on lynda.com when I saw [this lesson](http://www.lynda.com/Ruby-on-Rails-3-tutorials/essential-training/55960-2.html?srchtrk=index:0%0Alinktypeid:2%0Aq%3aruby%20on%20rails%0Apage:1%0As%3arelevance%0Asa%3atrue%0Aproducttypeid:2).

It's been great so far for learning the principles & theories of Rails, but it was made in 2010 and I've found out the hard way how much changes between major releases of Rails. For example, a *generated* project no longer contains a scripts folder - these are just called using the *rails* command in Mac's command line.

In the last lesson, the instructor generated a new rails project, added a controller:

```
class SayController < ApplicationController

  def hello
  end

end
```

and added a view (views -> say -> ['hello.rhtml'])

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello World</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

That was it. Next he just started up the rails server, jumped over to firefox, and entered the address `[http://localhost:3000/say/hello]`. The browser displayed the text "Hello World" as you would expect.

I, however, get "No route matches [GET] '/say/hello' ". I know this is a problem with routes, I just can't find a good (& RoR 4 specific) explanation of usage.

The line that seems to enable everything to work by default in the instructors project is:

```
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
```

I tried adding this (my routes.rb was generated with everything commented out), but it didn't work and I assume the RoR 4 convention is different.

So is there a default route for RoR 4? Does v4 not allow actions that return null or has the syntax changed?

The error page says my current route is `Rails.root: /Users/abcde/Sites/RoR/my_app/` which is where I have the rails server running, so I'm not sure if that matters.

The route trace & log just restate that my route (/say/hello/) doesn't exist), but I can post them if needed.

Comment: *.rhtml seems old too. Normally the views have the extension *.html.erb. If you're looking for help or documentation for Rails4 have a look at: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/ or especially http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html for routes.

Comment: I would also suggest [Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That syntax seems old, I would use:

```
get '/say/hello'
```

And if that does not work, I would specify controller and action:

```
get '/say/hello', to: 'say#hello'
```

Comment: Both give me the following error: Missing template say/hello, application/hello with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/Users/abcde/Sites/RoR/my_app/app/views"

Comment: ah yes, so you should follow @Ayonix comment, rename view file to `app/views/say/hello.html.erb`

Comment: Wonderful, working now. So I guess this means Rails 4 apps only accept explicit routes?

Comment: AFAIK accepts both... but I am not sure if connect is for Rails 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
match '/:controller/:action', :via => :get
```

should work!